# Different div positioning on different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am attempting to write a personal website and I am testing my website on a 1366x768 laptop screen, but also a 1920x1080 monitor attached to it. The layout of my divs looks perfectly on the laptop, but when I move the website across to the monitor, one of the div tags likes to move slightly (which is odd because the others seem fine.

Here is an image to illustrate my problem:

[image]

I want the border of the navigation div to align with the letters k and d, and this works fine on the top image which shows the laptop monitor, but as you can see on the image below the div shifts. The red lines show the actual alignment, and the green lines show what I want it to look like.

This is my CSS for the div:

```
nav{

    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    margin-left: 40%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    border: solid;

}
```

My logic here was that if I use percentages for my positioning then the div will adapt to different screen sizes and stay fixed in the same position, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Any ideas on how to fix it would be very appreciated.

Comment: is there a parent div with a width defined?

Comment: No, the whole thing is made up of 2 divs, one for the part with the text and the nav which is separate.

Comment: This is expected behavior for absolutely positioned elements with % margins.  20% away from the left on 1336 is a different number than 1920.  

I would suggest NOT positioning it absolutely.  Instead use a hard placed block and use margins

Comment: I agree with with briansol, if you need a better solution, please provide some more HTML and CSS code of this complete secton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the nav into the same div as the logo (lets say class .container).

```
.container { position:relative; }
```

Now just position the nav relative to the .container. It should be there on any resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my awful english, i'm practicing (i hope to have understood your request)

If you want use ABSOLUTE POSITION, you shall try this:
Insert the NAV into the TEXT container and then use this css

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: "your percentage";
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    border: solid;
}
```

in this way, you allways center the box (according to the parent container).